# Equivalent to for ((c=1; c<=5; c++)) for /bin/sh

Tags: shell, aix

I have the below code in shell for "for loop"

```
#!/bin/sh
for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ ))
do
    echo "welcome $c times"
done
```

On running:
./test.sh

Below is the error:

```
./test.sh[2]: syntax error at line 2 : '(' unexpected.
```

I have tried all possible ways to remove this error.

```
#!/bin/sh
for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ )); do
    echo "welcome $c times"
done
```

```
#!/bin/sh
for ( c=1; c<=5; c++ )
do
    echo "welcome $c times"
done
```

```
#!/bin/sh
for c=1; c<=5; c++
do
    echo "welcome $c times"
done
```

```
#!/bin/sh
for (c=1; c<=5; c++)
do
    echo "welcome $c times"
done
```

```
#!/bin/sh
for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ ));
do
    echo "welcome $c times"
done
```

I had read the other articles specifying bash. I do not have bash on my system so cannot use that.

Any workaround on .sh for this issue would be a great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI. I have edited my issue. You may take a look. Thanks!

Comment: If you stated what do you wish to achieve, we could help more. For example `seq 100 | while read N; do echo "N=$N"; done` is an option.

Comment: Do you have ksh?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, `seq` isn't POSIX-specified and is thus no more guaranteed to be available everywhere than `bash` itself is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sh` shell interpreter doesn't have the looping structure you are trying to use. You could use `bash` if it exists on your system, or change the loop to read like this

```
for c in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    echo "welcome $c times"
done
```

For larger loops where enumerating the values isn't reasonable you should implement the loop with `while`

```
c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    echo "welcome $c times"
    c=$((c+1))
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. As the data is too large I will try to use a while loop.